# pgpy: Decrypting a file produces a compressed file. Can't see how to uncompress it

Tags: python, pgp, openpgp

I'm trying to use pgpy to decrypt a text file with a private key.

I can load the file and it *seems* decrypt it OK, but after decryption the contents is still a PGP Message, and the object has is_compressed=true. There is no error on decryption.

Is there a decryption flag to decompress as well? Or am I missing something basic here?

```
import pgpy

key, _ = pgpy.PGPKey.from_file('/path/private_key_file')
with key.unlock('passphrase') as ukey:
    file_name = 'encrypted_file.pgp'
    # decrypt it
    enc_content=pgpy.PGPMessage.from_file(file_name)
    clr_content = key.decrypt(enc_content)
    
    # Write the content to a file
    # ...
```

I get a warning on the decryption line: UserWarning: Message was encrypted with this key's subkey: A85C839A50F35A9A. Decrypting with that...

At this point, clr_content.is_compressed = true and str(clr_content) looks like:

```
'-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----\n\nyP8AAOEdAnicxL3NcuPash54Oxwd0eEIv4EHGF3fG8bmwf
/PzCAIERBBgBsgpaMa\n+AQkokRskYQMkqWteol+E0d41ENHOPphet4DT5258EMSwAIgqY7PiSssct
8qVa6F\nXPmfX/6//+7f/NP/9X/8t//vP/3f699///f/9F//6d/8P//u8S/G6rfF78LfJE74\nm7H6
...
zn+3/Zud///2t+j997Uf0x940/eQbX/f6lx7656+8y/2l2k+9\n74fe/t+P/NGXPvGRr2sf+uIHHnr
tpz598PFvvf3/AYHoIHI=\n=cI/q\n-----END PGP MESSAGE-----\n'
```

I've tried pushing it through gzip, but didn't get anywhere.

Thanks in advance
Mike

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4880

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
clr_content = (key.decrypt(enc_content)).message
```

Having experimented a lot with this recently it seems that a decrypted `PGPMessage` is still a `PGPMessage` (obvious in retrospect) and to get the "clear" contents you need to retrieve the `.message` attribute of the object.